# Payment Issue - Magento 2.3.6

Tags: payment, magento2.3.6

I upgraded my Magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.6.

We have issues where the payment is now working anymore.
(https://lsxgarasjen.no/checkout/#payment)
If you inspect this page there is a lot off error and a error 500

In exception.log I get this error:

{ [2021-06-06 11:57:04] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-60bcb810c6427; Message: Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-60bcb810c6427; Message: Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path at /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): Infinite loop detected, review the trace for the looping path at /chroot/home/a96f0e0b/stores.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Session.php:241)"} [] }

I do use a 3rd party extension Nets Easy checkout, but the error messages are not from them.

I see error logs from Klarna and Magento.

Does anyone know what this can be?

Answer (score 0):

Found a quick fix for now, I took session.php from my Magento 2.3.3 version and replaced it with the 2.3.6 version. And payment is now working as normal.

Comment: Don't do that. You need to fix other way.

Comment: Do you have another solution?